# How can I reduce the size of this text

Tags: html, css

I have a minor cosmetic issue with some displayed text.  The code below displays some temperatures with a suffix of degrees F or degrees C, depending on the variable LineValue[0].  The output looks a little odd, however.  For some reason, the degree markers actually look a tiny bit larger than the text, and in any case the display looks a little off.  What I would like to do is display the degree marker slightly smaller than the main text, say about 3/4 the size of the previous text in the print statements.  One is set for 65px, the other for 108px.

index.txt:

```
div.Out {
    position: fixed;
    top: 45;
    left: 510;
    width: 300px;
    font: bold 65px Lora;
    color: white;
}
div.In {
    position: fixed;
    top: 214;
    left: 127;
    width: 400px;
    font: bold 108px Lora;
    color: rgb(0,44,255);
```

index.cgi:

```
with open("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.txt","r") as f:
    x = f.read()
    print(x)

print('<div class="Out">')
print('{0:5.1f}'.format(Tout), ClassValues[0][LineValue[0]])
print(</div)

print('<div class="In">')
if LineValue[0] == 0:
    Temperature = float(subprocess.check_output(["/usr/local/sbin/bme280", "-C"])) + COffset # Print Temperature in degrees Celsius
    print('{0:5.1f}'.format(Temperature), ClassValues[0][0])
else:
    Temperature = float(subprocess.check_output(["/usr/local/sbin/bme280", "-F"])) + FOffset # Print Temperature in degrees Farenheight
    print(Temperature, ClassValues[0][1])
print('</div>')
```

ClassValues[0] has the value [℃,℉]

Python code output:

```
<div class="Out">
 25.8 &#8451;
</div>
<div class="In">
 25.3 &#8451;
```

Comment: You can wrap the unit in a `span` and set a different `font-size` for the same

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful if you can create a code snippet with the associated HTML instead of the python code

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python actually (tag removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
print('<div class="Out">')
print('{0:5.1f}'.format(Tout),'<span style="font-size:44px">', ClassValues[0][LineValue[0]], '</span>', sep="")

print('<div class="In">')
if LineValue[0] == 0:
    Temperature = float(subprocess.check_output(["/usr/local/sbin/bme280", "-C"])) + COffset # Print Temperature in degrees Celsius
    print('{0:5.1f}'.format(Temperature),'<span style="font-size:76px">', ClassValues[0][0], '</span>', sep="")
else:
    Temperature = float(subprocess.check_output(["/usr/local/sbin/bme280", "-F"])) + FOffset # Print Temperature in degrees Farenheight
    print(Temperature, '<span style="font-size:76px">', ClassValues[0][1], '</span>', sep="")
print('</div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap temperature unit into a tag + css

```css
div.In {
  width: 400px;
  font: bold 108px Lora;
}
mySmall {
  font-size: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="In">
 25.8 <small>&#8451;</small>
</div>

<div class="In">
 25.8 <mySmall>&#8451;</mySmall>
</div>
```